# how to used custom date format 'MM/DD/YYYY H:MM am/pm' in moment.js?

Tags: angular, momentjs

I have used angular4 and moment.js. My custom format is:- 'MM/DD/YYYY H:MM am/pm' I have no idea how to use this format.

Component.ts:-

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
ngOnInit() {
  moment(1503491583*1000).format('MM/DD/YYYY H:MM am/pm');
}
```

Output:- 08/23/2017 18:08 pm3/p3

This output is wrong. Please tell us how to get Output is '08/23/2017 18:08 pm'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `a` token, see [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) docs.

Please note that you have to use lowercase `mm` to get minutes, while uppercase `MM` is for months.

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
ngOnInit() {
  moment(1503491583*1000).format('MM/DD/YYYY H:mm a');
}
```

You are getting `pm3/p3` because `am/pm` is interpreted as:

- `a` => `am` or `pm` (`pm` for your case)
- `m` as minutes (`3` in your case)
- `p` as the `p` character

---

As a side note, moment has the [`moment.unix(Number)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/) method to parse seconds since Unix Epoch and as the docs says:

> This is implemented as `moment(timestamp * 1000)`, so partial seconds in the input timestamp are included.

You can use `moment.unix(503491583)` instead of `moment(1503491583*1000)` to get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS, MomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import { DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-details',
  templateUrl: './user-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-details.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS },
    // {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
  ],
})
export class UserDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  userDetailsFormGroup = this.fb.group({
    firstName: [''],
    lastName: [''],
    username: [''],
    address: ['', Validators.required],
    dob: [moment(), Validators.required],
    gender: ['', Validators.required],
    contactNumber: ['', Validators.required],
  });



   updateUserProfile() {

   const dobDate = this.userDetailsFormGroup.controls.dob.value;
     const momentDOB1 = dobDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY');

       const body = {
      'firstName': this.userDetailsFormGroup.controls.firstName.value,
      'lastName': this.userDetailsFormGroup.controls.lastName.value,
      'address': this.userDetailsFormGroup.controls.address.value,
      'dob': momentDOB1,
      'gender': this.userDetailsFormGroup.controls.gender.value,
      'contactNumber': this.userDetailsFormGroup.controls.contactNumber.value

    };


    // call http method here
   }


   getUserProfileData(){

   //get http 
    this.http.get<any>(AppSettings.BASE_URL + '/v1/userProfile/getMyProfile').pipe()
      .subscribe(
          data => {
              const dateDob = moment(data.dob, 'MM/DD/YYYY');
              console.log('getting date format :::');
              console.log(dateDob.toISOString());
              this.userDetailsFormGroup.controls.dob.setValue(dateDob);
          }
      );
}
```

Comment: updateUserProfile method for set date in MM/DD/YYYY formate in databse, and     getUserProfile method for setting MM/DD/YYYY formate string in datepicker of angualr application